# Undefined reference error using CImg in C++

Tags: c++, cimg

I'm using CImg for image processing, and I wanted to try a very simple example that turns some pixels of an image to black:

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include<X11/Xlib.h>
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace cimg_library;

int main()
{
    // read a jpg image
    CImg<float> imgin("frog.jpg");
    // do some computation on the pixels (R,G,B values)
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
            imgin(i,i+j,0) = imgin(i,i+j,1) = imgin(i, i+j, 2) = 0;
    // write image back
    imgin.save("frog2.jpg");
    return(0);
}
```

I compiled my program in different ways:

`g++ -L/usr/lib -lm -lpthread -lX11 -O3 -o try main.cpp`

`g++ -L/usr/libX11 -lm -lpthread -lX11 -O3 -o try main.cpp`

`g++ -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lm -lpthread -lX11 -O3 -o try main.cpp`

but I always get the same error:

```
    /tmp/ccQmlT63.o: In function `cimg_library::CImgDisplay::paint(bool) [clone .part.18]':
main.cpp:(.text+0x4f2): undefined reference to `XPutImage'
main.cpp:(.text+0x625): undefined reference to `XSendEvent'
/tmp/ccQmlT63.o: In function `cimg_library::CImgDisplay::move(int, int) [clone .part.142]':
main.cpp:(.text+0xe6a): undefined reference to `XMoveWindow'
main.cpp:(.text+0x109c): undefined reference to `XSendEvent'
/tmp/ccQmlT63.o: In function `cimg_library::CImgDisplay::_events_thread(void*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv]+0xe8): undefined reference to `XCheckTypedEvent'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv]+0x100): undefined reference to `XCheckMaskEvent'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv]+0x124): undefined reference to `pthread_testcancel'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv]+0x4d2): undefined reference to `XUnmapWindow'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv]+0x574): undefined reference to `XCheckWindowEvent'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv]+0x5ca): undefined reference to `XResizeWindow'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv]+0x65e): undefined reference to `XLookupString'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv]+0x8a4): undefined reference to `XCheckWindowEvent'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv]+0x9bc): undefined reference to `XCheckWindowEvent'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv]+0xa75): undefined reference to `XCheckWindowEvent'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv]+0xb14): undefined reference to `XCheckWindowEvent'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv]+0xb79): undefined reference to `XPutImage'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv]+0xb9b): undefined reference to `XGetWindowAttributes'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv]+0xbac): undefined reference to `XSync'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv]+0xbc9): undefined reference to `XSetInputFocus'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv]+0xc70): undefined reference to `XCheckWindowEvent'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv]+0xecc): undefined reference to `XCheckWindowEvent'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv]+0xf17): undefined reference to `XQueryKeymap'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay14_events_threadEPv]+0xf63): undefined reference to `XLookupString'
/tmp/ccQmlT63.o: In function `cimg_library::CImgDisplay::_set_colormap(unsigned long&, unsigned int)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay13_set_colormapERmj[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay13_set_colormapERmj]+0x280): undefined reference to `XStoreColors'
/tmp/ccQmlT63.o: In function `cimg_library::CImgDisplay::_map_window()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay11_map_windowEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay11_map_windowEv]+0x5c): undefined reference to `XMapRaised'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay11_map_windowEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay11_map_windowEv]+0x73): undefined reference to `XWindowEvent'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay11_map_windowEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay11_map_windowEv]+0xae): undefined reference to `XGetWindowAttributes'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay11_map_windowEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay11_map_windowEv]+0xbf): undefined reference to `XSync'
/tmp/ccQmlT63.o: In function `cimg_library::CImgDisplay::_paint(bool)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6_paintEb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6_paintEb]+0x87): undefined reference to `XPutImage'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6_paintEb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6_paintEb]+0xfd): undefined reference to `XSendEvent'
/tmp/ccQmlT63.o: In function `cimg_library::CImgDisplay::assign()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6assignEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6assignEv]+0x5ed): undefined reference to `XDestroyWindow'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6assignEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6assignEv]+0x63f): undefined reference to `XSync'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6assignEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6assignEv]+0x989): undefined reference to `XUngrabKeyboard'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6assignEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6assignEv]+0xd0b): undefined reference to `XFreeColormap'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6assignEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6assignEv]+0xd18): undefined reference to `XDestroyWindow'
/tmp/ccQmlT63.o: In function `cimg_library::CImgDisplay::screen_height()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay13screen_heightEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay13screen_heightEv]+0xfb): undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay13screen_heightEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay13screen_heightEv]+0x11d): undefined reference to `XCloseDisplay'
/tmp/ccQmlT63.o: In function `cimg_library::CImgDisplay::screen_width()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay12screen_widthEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay12screen_widthEv]+0xfb): undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay12screen_widthEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay12screen_widthEv]+0x11d): undefined reference to `XCloseDisplay'
/tmp/ccQmlT63.o: In function `cimg_library::CImgDisplay::_init_fullscreen()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv]+0xcf): undefined reference to `XCreateWindow'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv]+0x148): undefined reference to `XCreateImage'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv]+0x16b): undefined reference to `XSelectInput'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv]+0x17a): undefined reference to `XMapRaised'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv]+0x193): undefined reference to `XWindowEvent'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv]+0x1d3): undefined reference to `XPutImage'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv]+0x1eb): undefined reference to `XGetWindowAttributes'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay16_init_fullscreenEv]+0x206): undefined reference to `XSync'
/tmp/ccQmlT63.o: In function `cimg_library::CImgDisplay::_assign(unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*, unsigned int, bool, bool)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x2e0): undefined reference to `XCreateWindow'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x303): undefined reference to `XSelectInput'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x325): undefined reference to `XStoreName'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x339): undefined reference to `XAllocClassHint'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x366): undefined reference to `XSetClassHint'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x36e): undefined reference to `XFree'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x3ec): undefined reference to `XCreateImage'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x409): undefined reference to `XInternAtom'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x422): undefined reference to `XInternAtom'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x445): undefined reference to `XSetWMProtocols'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x688): undefined reference to `XCreateSimpleWindow'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x6c6): undefined reference to `XGrabKeyboard'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x713): undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x78d): undefined reference to `XVisualIDFromVisual'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x7ac): undefined reference to `XGetVisualInfo'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x7e5): undefined reference to `XFree'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x81e): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x85b): undefined reference to `XMapRaised'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x877): undefined reference to `XWindowEvent'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x8be): undefined reference to `XGetWindowAttributes'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x8d1): undefined reference to `XSync'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0x95e): undefined reference to `XCreateColormap'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0xf9f): undefined reference to `XStoreColors'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay7_assignEjjPKcjbb]+0xfc5): undefined reference to `XSetWindowColormap'
/tmp/ccQmlT63.o: In function `cimg_library::CImgDisplay::resize(int, int, bool)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6resizeEiib[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6resizeEiib]+0x34d): undefined reference to `XResizeWindow'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6resizeEiib[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6resizeEiib]+0x361): undefined reference to `XGetWindowAttributes'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6resizeEiib[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6resizeEiib]+0x57d): undefined reference to `XCreateImage'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6resizeEiib[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6resizeEiib]+0x76b): undefined reference to `XSendEvent'
/tmp/ccQmlT63.o: In function `cimg_library::CImgDisplay& cimg_library::CImgDisplay::assign<unsigned char>(cimg_library::CImg<unsigned char> const&, char const*, unsigned int, bool, bool)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6assignIhEERS0_RKNS_4CImgIT_EEPKcjbb[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay6assignIhEERS0_RKNS_4CImgIT_EEPKcjbb]+0x299): undefined reference to `XSendEvent'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

After searching on google, I also tried:

`sudo apt-get install libx11-dev` (but looks like I already have it)

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/xorg /usr/X11R6` (because there is no X11R6 folder under `/usr`)

but none of these solved the issue. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to put libraries at the end of your command:

```
g++ -O3 -o try main.cpp -lm -lpthread -lX11
```

The linker will fulfill dependencies from left to right. Anything on the left of the command line cannot fulfill dependencies of something to its right (in general, there are exceptions of course).

Comment: Thank you, very simple and straightforward solution!